# Does anyone recognize this ceiling fan brand?

Tags: ceiling-fan

There are no identifying brand marks on the exterior of the fan. Year 2000 or newer. I suspect the black dome on the canopy might be a sensor for a remote and would like to pick one up but need to figure out the right brand.

[image: Unknown Ceiling Fan]

Comment: Where are you on this planet? Can you take some of the covers off and try to hunt for a listing label on the thing?

Comment: Sorry I should have specified United States.

Comment: Does the fan have a UL/CSA/ETL label on it anywhere?

Comment: Not on the outside. If no one recognizes it I'll try pulling it apart to look inside.

Comment: Yes, remove the fan canopy and there may be a label on the inside of the housing. Also get up there and look at the top of the motor housing for a label.